# Which elements in "The Changeling" are supernatural, if any?

Tags: the-changeling

In the 2023 TV series *The Changeling*, there are lots of elements that are apparently magical: witches, fairies, and so forth.

Some of the elements seem more supernatural than others—for instance,
unless the show is just showing us Emma's incorrect perspective and Emma is supposed to have *actually* killed her baby, which seems unlikely, then he really would seem to have been a changeling made of only a tree branch and bit of soil. And then other things seem less clear: is William Wheeler actually some kind of demon or just a violent man? Is the island really protected by powerful magic that only Apollo could bypass, or are Wheeler and Cal just out of touch with reality?

To what extent is there actual magic present in *The Changeling*, and to what extent is it supposed to be ambiguous (or even unambiguously mundane)?

Comment: Don't know about the show but according to this spoiler review of the book it's based on  the magic is real: https://cannonballread.com/2017/09/the-changeling-ale/